# Is there a way to get a nested Eloquent model based on ids from another table?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

**Hey there stackoverflow**

I am currently building a course application as part of my laravel project.

My problem lies in how the eloquent handle model relations, i'm still kinda new to eloquent, so hopefully you can answer my question.

**The structure**

The Course has many episodes and each episode has many sections.

Which means I have 3 tables in the DB. **Courses -> course_episodes -> course_episode_sections**

ID table is where i connect courses with users - **course_users**.

Right now i can create courses and and put in all the data correctly.

**The Problem**

I need to retrieve all the courses and its nested children that the user has bought, which is connected in the **course_users** table with columns **course_id and user_id**

**Course structure**

Same stucture in DB

```
                course: {
                name: null,
                sub_title: null,
                estimate: null,
                trailer: null,
                type: null,
                text: null,

                course_episodes: [
                    {
                        name: null,
                        section: [
                            {
                                order: null,
                                type: null,
                                content: null,
                            },
                        ]
                    },
                ]

            }
```

**Model Pictures**

My models as of right now.

```
class CourseUsers extends Model {
protected $fillable = [
    'id',
    'course_id',
    'user_id',
    'active',
];

protected $hidden = [
    'deleted_at',
    'updated_at',
    'deleted_at'
];


public function courses()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Course::class);
}

public function user(){

    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

public function scopeFindForUserId($query, $userId)
{
    return $query->where(function ($q) use ($userId) {
        $q->where(function ($q) use ($userId) {
            $q->where('user_id', $userId);
        });
    });
}
```

**Course model**

```
class Course extends Model{
protected $fillable = [
    'id',
    'name',
    'sub_title',
    'type',
    'estimate',
    'trailer',
    'gateway_id',
    'text',
    'active',
];


protected $hidden = [
    'deleted_at',
    'updated_at',
    'deleted_at'
];


public function courseEpisode()
{
    return $this->hasMany(CourseEpisode::class);
}

public function courseUsers() {

    return $this->hasMany(CourseUsers::class);
}

public function scopeActive(Builder $builder)
{
    return $builder->where('active', true);
}
```

**Course episode Model**

```
class CourseEpisode extends Model implements HasMedia {
use HasMediaTrait;

protected $fillable = [
    'id',
    'course_id',
    'order',
    'name',

];

protected $hidden = [
    'deleted_at',
    'updated_at',
    'deleted_at'
];

public function course()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Course::class);
}

public function courseSection()
{
    return $this->hasMany(CourseEpisodeSection::class);
}
```

**Course episode sections**

```
class CourseEpisodeSection extends Model {

protected $fillable = [
    'id',
    'course_episode_id',
    'order',
    'type',
    'content'

];

protected $hidden = [
    'deleted_at',
    'updated_at',
    'deleted_at'
];

public function courseEpisode()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(CourseEpisode::class);
}
```

Comment: Please post the code in the question instead of the links.

Comment: Don't post your Database Tables/Models as images... Stackoverflow supports tables, and otherwise code is text; copy and paste into your question, with proper formatting. We have to click 8 links to see what your issue is, and that's just too much.

Comment: One thing you should probably think about is a naming scheme for your models. You currently have a model called `Course` and `CourseEpisode` but then one called `CourseUsers`. Models should be singular.

Comment: So if I understand the question correctly, you want to get all `Course`s and related `CourseEpisode`s which are connected to the user? I'd suggest looking through the [Eloquent relationship docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships). Based on your description, everything you need should be there.

Comment: @YaakovAinspan Yes i want to look through the course_users table and find all the courses the specific user has bought. But i need to get all the Courses and its nested children in the process.

Comment: @YaakovAinspan I've tried looking through the docs but i feel stuck on finding a solution because of the nested problem

Comment: Please share the content of your user model as well. I need to see what is the name of the relation for the course modal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your explanation, course_users table holds many-to-many relationship between Course and User model. In case of a many-to-many relationship, you actually don't need a CourseUser model. This kind of table which holds many-to-many relationship is called pivot table. Read more from the [Official Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

I am defining only the relationships with your Course, User, CourseEpisode, CourseEpisodeSection models.

Course.php

```
class Course extends Model
{
  public function courseEpisodes()
  {
    return $this->hasMany(CourseEpisode::class);
  }

  public function users()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class,'course_users')->withPivot('active');
  }
}
```

CourseEpisode.php

```
class CourseEpisode extends Model
{
  public function courseSections()
  {
    return $this->hasMany(CourseSection::class);
  }
}
```

User.php

```
class User
{
  public function courses()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Course::class,'course_users')->withPivot('active');
  }
}
```

If you want to get all the children relationships from a user, use nested [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) :

```
$user_with_nested_course_data = User::with('courses.courseEpisodes.courseSections')->find($id);
```

Comment: It works!, thanks a lot for the help and a very informing answer. :-)